# how to change the text of a button once that button is pressed

Tags: java, button, netbeans

I have a button called Connect once I press the connect button I want the text of that button to be disconnect. So when the user starts the application it will be connect and once the button is clicked it will be disconnect when the user wants to close the application they will hit disconnect.

Is that possible to do this?

Comment: Share the relevant code snippets you have tried yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans is very intuitive and easy to use... try this:

## Declare

```
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
```

## Construct and set Lsitener

```
   jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

## Get Click Action Event

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jButton2.setText("Hello");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the below code snippet will work for you

```
 connectBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            connectBtn.setText("Dissconnect");
        }

    });
```

`connectBtn` is instance of your Button Component